# Letsencrypt + Docker + Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker

I am referring this link https://miki725.github.io/docker/crypto/2017/01/29/docker+nginx+letsencrypt.html
to enable SSL on my app which is running along with docker. So the problem here is when I run the below command

```
  docker run -it --rm \
  -v certs:/etc/letsencrypt \
  -v certs-data:/data/letsencrypt \
  deliverous/certbot \
  certonly \
  --webroot --webroot-path=/data/letsencrypt \
  -d api.mydomain.com
```

It throws an error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. api.mydomain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://api.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/OCy4HSmhDwb2dtBEjZ9vP3HgjVXDPeghSAdqMFOFqMw:
```

So can any one please help me and let me know if I am missing something or doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What seems to be missing from that article and possibly from your setup is that the hostname `api.mydomain.com` needs to have a public DNS record pointing to the IP address of the machine on which the Nginx container is running.

The Let's Encrypt process is trying to access the file `api.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/OCy4HSmhDwb2dtBEjZ9vP3HgjVXDPeghSAdqMFOFqMw`. This file is put there by `certbot`. If the address `api.mydomain.com` does not resolve to the address of the machine from which you are running certbot then the process will fail.

You will also need to have ports 80 and 443 open for it to work.

Based on the available info that is my best suggestion on where you can start looking to resolve the issue.