# Docker LetsEncrypt auto-renewal in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, docker, https

I have a .NET application that I have dockerized. I want to deploy it in Azure, however I am having trouble configuring an HTTPS LetsEncrypt certificate that auto renews.

From looking online I see most solutions involve setting up a 'side-car container' which uses the Certbot image and runs some kind of cron job.

However from my understanding, this means I would end up with 2 images, one for certbot and one for my app, and so would need to pay for 2 containers in Azure rather than one. Is that correct? Or is it possible to deploy 2 docker containers to a single Azure container service?

It seems silly to pay for an extra Azure container service which only handles the auto-renewal of a different container service. I feel like I am misunderstanding something here. What is the easiest/cheapest solution to certificate auto-renewal for Docker/.NET in Azure?

Comment: Where are you running your containerized application? App Service, Azure Container Instances, Azure Kubernetes Service or something else?

Comment: there are alternatives to run the cert bot container. E.g. Azure Container Instance is serverless,

Comment: I haven't chosen yet as I don't know what is best to do

Comment: Does the below so thread helpful ?, building the lets encrypt on a [single stand alone container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810100/how-to-configure-letsencrypt-cerbot-in-a-standalone-container) 
Here is reference blog for more information https://miki725.com/docker/crypto/2017/01/29/docker+nginx+letsencrypt.html

Comment: So that is using a single container for just certbot. I am wanting a single container for my app AND certbot to avoid paying for two containers just to get HTTPS renewal